# 8 Bit Mirror's Edge

Tags: game-identification, mirrors-edge

I was reading few blogs and stuff about 8 bit Mirror's Edge. See the screenshot.

[image]

I searched for it all over the net but I couldn't find it. Is it really made or it's just some animators having fun?

Source: [cimota.com](http://cimota.com/blog/2012/04/)

Comment: Why am I  downvoted?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but this question is fairly trivially answered by Google Image search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are mockup images created by Swedish pixel artist [Junkboy](http://jnkboy.tumblr.com/) for contemporary video game [demakes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_remake#.22Demakes.22). You can see them on his tumblr [here](http://jnkboy.tumblr.com/post/69187692106/old-demakes-2), as well as [other video game demake mockups](http://jnkboy.tumblr.com/search/demake).

Comment: Junkboy is awesome.  Check out some of his work for Ubiktune as well.

Comment: Oh man, I really wish it was there in real. Looks fun. Anyway thanks.